# How to deploy python FLASK API?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have created a api using flask in python. I am done with development. Now I want to deploy it. Can anyone help me that where can i deploy my api and how?

Comment: try heroku or aws server.

Comment: you should find server before you start creating it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many services(PaaS) that you can use to deploy your app. I personally use [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

You can use AWS also from the free tier account. If you just google you will find many options( OpenShift, CapRover, Digital Ocean,etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try  the deployment of flask  api with Ubuntu .